# Salesforce for Outlook - Side Panel error when trying to add an email - We couldn't add this item. Please try adding this item again

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

When you select an email in Outlook, in Inbox or any other folder as well as composing a new email, or even replying to an email and trying to associate that email to a record in Salesforce using the Side Panel, the Side Panel throws an error message on top after you click on the Envelope icon next to the record name

I have written a trigger on task and event.As soon as i deactivates the trigger this works.But when the triggers are active , I am able to create a new task from + icon but not through a task feature of outlook.

Can you please guide me with the error

Best Regards,
Samir

Comment: Might help if you post the trigger code.  I recall seeing other SFO issues that seemed to be related to how account is set on the task/event when created by SFO.  I beleive account might be blank when created and then set.  You could also turn on debug logging for the user and add some debugging to your trigger, which could get you more info on what is failing.

Comment: You are correct.With Salesforce for Outlook, associations are completed after the Task is created, so the Task.WhoId and Task.WhatId fields aren’t immediately available for insert and update events, and their values are initially null. The WhoId and WhatId fields are set on the saved task record in a subsequent operation, however, so their values can be retrieved later. This is why on Create, via SFO, the Process is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a long research i came to know what went wrong in my trigger and why i was not able to create a task or event from the side panel in outlook.In my trigger i have been using whoid and whatid.The problem is when the trigger get fired from the outlook to salesforce, Whoid and whatid are not immediately available for trigger.That's why my trigger was failing.

The workaround would be to check if the whoid and whatid are null or not.If they are null,then pass the taskid or eventid to future method.

Please let me know if I have been wrong somewhere or someone has some better workaround for this